# python3 non-blocking fifo open

Tags: python-3.x, fifo

I'm trying to write a simple program that open a file (for reading), get some status and then close the file.  
But when the file is a FIFO, my program hang, because the Python open is blocking when the file is a FIFO.  
One solution may be to create a thread to write into the FIFO. But I'm pretty sure there is a better solution.

Can somebody suggest a better approach?

Comment: look into using `asyncio`

Comment: @ParkerD I don't see how asyncio can solve the problem. asyncio is good for CPU-bound problems. But it does nothing to blocking IO services. But if you show me a track, I will follow it.

Comment: You've got it backwards, `asyncio` is made for IO-bound tasks -- hence async**io**

Comment: Maybe try using https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles